# Email Address with atleast 2 Character domain extension

Tags: asp.net

I am using this one

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
  ValidationExpression="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$" 
  Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" >
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

1) abc@example.c is valid in this case. Is this ok a/g to the standards?

2) what should i include in the expression, if it has to check that there are atleast 2 letters after the dot.
abc@example.co

Comment: Try this `@"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
     + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
    [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
     + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
    [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
     + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to validate a email-adress in my applications i use:

```
ValidationExpression="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.(\w{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$"
```

if u want to validate 2 letters after the dot. use `\w{2}` like:

```
 ValidationExpression="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w{2}$"
```

Comment: Thank you.That is working. But it doesnt accept aaa@example.w2w - So, my first question remains unanswered. Are 'aaa@example.w2w' & 'aaa@example.w' acceptable a/g to industry standards?

Comment: imho no. i havn't ever seen such standarts. However if u want them to be valid put `(\w{2}|w2w|w)` at the end instead of `\w{2}`.